# Django forms how to display related data in an inner form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am struggling with Django forms.
I have the following model.py:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey("portfolios.Portfolio", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class PropertyImage(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey("Property", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = property_image_upload_to)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url


class PropertyDocument(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey("Property", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.FileField()


class Address(models.Model):
    property = models.OneToOneField("Property", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    line3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When adding/updating a property, I want the form to show the form for related objects like the address, documents/images instead of the select list's that appear in forms - I want to be able to add/edit the related data.

My view.py file

```
class PropertyCreate(CreateView):
    model = Property
    form_class=PropertyAddressFormSet
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Property_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PropertyCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return data
```

Property_form.html

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <button class="btn btn-link" onclick="javascript:history.back();">Cancel</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from . import views

app_name = 'properties'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:portfolio_id>/<int:pk>/edit', views.PropertyUpdate.as_view(), name='property_edit'),
    path('<int:portfolio_id>/create', views.PropertyCreate.as_view(), name='property_new'),
]
```

I've read about inlineformset_factories and inlineformset's etc, but is this the best choice for my scenario? If so, I can't figure out how to show the portfolio, address form

I;m currently using a inlineformset like so, which creates the Address form on the PropertyCreate view, but I want to also add in the PropertyImages and PropertyDocs to the ProertyCreate view.:

```
PropertyAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=Property, 
    model=Address, 
    form=AddressForm, 
    extra=0,
    min_num=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the same boat as me, I managed to get this working with the following code:

Forms.py:

```
class PropertyForm(ModelForm):
    """ Edit a property """
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        exclude = ()

PropertyAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=Property, 
    model=Address, 
    form=AddressForm, 
    extra=0,
    min_num=1
)
```

Views.py

```
class PropertyCreate(CreateView):
    model = Property
    form_class=PropertyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Property_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PropertyCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
        data['address'] = PropertyAddressFormSet (self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        data['address'] = PropertyAddressFormSet ()
    return data
```

template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form |crispy }}
    <fieldset class="border p-2">
        <legend class="w-auto">Address</legend>
        {{ address.management_form }}
        {% for form in address.forms %}
        <div >
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope this helps someone.